# How to test head() in nuxt.js using jest

Tags: unit-testing, vue.js, jestjs, nuxt.js

I am using Nuxt.js with Jest for unit testing. I added a head function in my layout to change the title and I would like to unit test it.
Here is my file:

```html
<template>
  <h1 class="title">HELLO</h1>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data () {
    return {
      title: 'MY TITLE'
    }
  },
  head () {
    return {
      title: this.title,
      meta: [
        { hid: 'description', name: 'description', content: 'MY DESCRIPTION' }
      ]
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

I tried:

```
const wrapper = shallowMount(index)
wrapper.vm.head() <- fails
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 6):

Inject `vue-meta` plugin in the Vue instance used for mounting the component. You can then access `head()` data with `wrapper.vm.$metaInfo`. See example below.

**pageOrLayoutToTest.vue**

```html
<template>
  <h1 class="title">HELLO</h1>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data () {
    return {
      title: 'MY TITLE'
    }
  },
  head () {
    return {
      title: this.title,
      meta: [
        { hid: 'description', name: 'description', content: 'MY DESCRIPTION' }
      ]
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

**pageOrLayoutToTest.spec.js**

```js
import { shallowMount, createLocalVue } from '@vue/test-utils'
import VueMeta from 'vue-meta'

// page or layout to test
import pageOrLayoutToTest from '@/path/to/pageOrLayoutToTest.vue'

// create vue with vue-meta
const localVue = createLocalVue()
localVue.use(VueMeta, { keyName: 'head' })

describe('pageOrLayoutToTest.vue', () => {
  let wrapper;

  // test set up
  beforeEach(() => {
    wrapper = shallowMount(pageOrLayoutToTest, {
      localVue
    })
  })

  // test tear down
  afterEach(() => {
    if (wrapper) {
      wrapper.destroy()
    }
  })

  it('has correct <head> content', () => {
    // head data injected by the page or layout to test is accessible with
    // wrapper.vm.$metaInfo. Note that this object will not contain data
    // defined in nuxt.config.js.

    // test title
    expect(wrapper.vm.$metaInfo.title).toBe('MY TITLE')

    // test meta entry
    const descriptionMeta = wrapper.vm.$metaInfo.meta.find(
      (item) => item.hid === 'description'
    )
    expect(descriptionMeta.content).toBe('MY DESCRIPTION')
  })
})
```

Comment: This is one of the Nuxt-related answers you didn't think would work, but does. I fully expected this test case to be nerve-wracking given how hard to test Nuxt stores.

Answer (score 0):

head() can be accessed by:

```
wrp.vm.$options.head()
```

Another, maybe better way for testing is to extract function to separate file.